# Extracting bad records from flat files using awk

Tags: awk

Need a script to extract the row in the file which contains more than specified columns using `awk`?

Comment: Duplicate of [Removal of lines with no more or fewer than 'N' fields?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151658/80216)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NF > 10 { print NR }' data.in
```

This will print the line numbers (actually the *record* numbers, but since a line is a record by default there's no difference) of each line containing more than 10 fields. A field is a string delimited by whitespace by default, if you have another delimiter, use `-F` (`-F ','` for commas):

```
$ awk -F ',' 'NF > 10 { print NR }' data.in
```

If you want to see the line rather than its line number, it's even easier:

```
$ awk 'NF > 10' data.in
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is: how can I print lines from a file that have more than "max" number of columns, here's one way:

```
awk -v max=9 'NF > max' your-file-here
```

pass in whatever value for max (here, 9) that you want to specify.

Answer (score 1):

If by extracting you mean removing you can use `awk`

```
$ awk 'NF < 10' my-file.in > my-file.out
```

Breakdown

`NF` is an awk variable which shows how many fields there are in the current line being processed.

`< 10` If NF is less than 10 it will print the line.

`my-file.in` The input file.

`> my-file.out` Redirect output to a new file.

If you want to read more about awk and it's built in's I found this pretty nice layout of the built-in awk variables [here](https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_11.html).

Comment: you may have better luck (depending on your geography, maybe) - with the [canonical gawk link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables)