# Check number of columns and move file accordingly

Tags: awk, mv

I get hundred's of .txt files with 9 columns and 11 columns. I need to look at the number of columns and move 9 column file to another directory.

Comment: Post what you have come up with so far.

Comment: post a testable fragment of your *.txt files with 9 columns and 11 columns*

Comment: how do you move a column of text to a directory? Sample input and output are needed.

Comment: Related:  [Removal of lines with no more or fewer than 'N' fields?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151658/80216)

Comment: in a directory, there are many .txt file (pipe delimited). Each text file may have 9, 10, 11 or 12 columns. Need to identify these files (based on columns) and move it to new directory based on number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean columns in the manner how `awk` recognizes columns, then you can use this:

```
awk 'NF==9{printf "%s\0", FILENAME}{nextfile}' * | xargs -0 mv -t /path/to/dir
```

**Explanation**

- `NF==9` checks if the line has 9 columns
- `printf "%s\0", FILENAME` prints the filename null-byte delimited
- `nextfile` continues with the next file
- `xargs -0` reads the list null-byte delimited
- `mv -t target` moves all matched file to `target` directory